# "tsc -w" does not watch for changes in virtual machine (Vagrant) when files are changed in the host machine

Tags: typescript, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm following the [Angular2 Tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial) and cloned the repo inside the virtual machine that I created with Vagrant. The folder is synced with the host machine so that I can use my editor in the host machine. When I run `tsc -w` and edit the files while I'm inside the guest machine everything works perfectly, it detects the changes. However when I edit the files in my host machine (assuming because of the sync with the guest machine tsc will detect the file changes) tsc does not detect the changes and thus does not recompile. Is it a problem with how tsc is watching the files or do I have to configure Vagrant in a different way?

Comment: how do you sync the folder ?

Comment: I tried [VirtualBox's shared folder system](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/virtualbox.html) (which is the default for Vagrant VirtualBox provider) and [nfs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/nfs.html). Couldn't succeed in any of them unfortunately. I didn't try rsync, because it only syncs on vagrant up/reload

Comment: clear `rsync` would not work, I thought you did it this way - I am not sure then, normally it should work with vagrant, its slow though but it works

Comment: how slow is it in your case? I waited for more than a couple of minutes but still couldn't see anything

Comment: no its not immediate but its a matter of seconds (vs real time if everything is local) do you see the file change on VM file disk within seconds too or its too long as well ?

Comment: I see the file change on VM disk within seconds